# Problemas simples con arrays PHP

Tags: php, array

al grano, declaré un array vació, en el cual pienso guardar valores enteros aleatorios haciendo uso de una función y esto es lo que hice, pero al hacer el count($array), me salen 0 elementos.

Ejemplo:

```
$numerosJ1 = array();
numerosJugadores($numerosJ1);

function numerosJugadores($arreglo) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $numero = rand(1, 45);
        $arreglo[$i] = $numero;
        echo $numero." ";
    }
}

echo count($numerosJ1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muy sencillo: estás pasando `$numerosJ1` **por copia**; es decir, adentro de tu función `numerosJugadores( )` está llegando una copia de tu array, **no** el array original; dentro de esa función añades cosas ... pero **a la copia**, no al original.

Consecuencia de esto: tu array original `$numerosJ1` **no cambia**, puesto que realmente no lo estás usando.

Para solucionarlo, basta con pasarlo **por referencia** (indicándolo al declarar la función):

```
$numerosJ1 = array( );
numerosJugadores( $numerosJ1 );

function numerosJugadores( &$arreglo ) {
  for( $i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
    $numero = rand( 1, 45 );
    $arreglo[$i] = $numero;
    echo $numero." ";
  }
}

echo count( $numerosJ1 );
```

Como ves, el único cambio ha sido ese, indicar al intérprete de PHP que la función requiere pasar el argumento como una referencia:

```
function numerosJugadores( &$arreglo ) {
```

Al hacerlo así, no se crea una copia, y tu función trabaja con el *arreglo* original.

Comment: Acabo de probar esa solución y me funcionó, además gracias por la explicación de porqué no funcionaba lo que hice :D.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que es más simple hacer esto. Al menos a simple vista hay menos trasiego de variables y puede que ganes en rendimiento:

```
$numerosJ1 = numerosJugadores();

function numerosJugadores() {
    $arreglo=array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
        $numero = rand(1, 45);
        $arreglo[$i] = $numero;
        echo $numero." ";
    }
return $arreglo;
}

echo count($numerosJ1);
```

Al menos es como suelo resolver este tipo de problemas.

---

En cuanto a la solución que propone @Trauma, la cual por cierto debe ser escrita **indicando en la función, no en la llamada a la misma**, que el valor que pasamos es por referencia...

```
$numerosJ1 = array();
numerosJugadores( $numerosJ1 );

function numerosJugadores( &$arreglo ) {
  for( $i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++ ) {
    $numero = rand( 1, 45 );
    $arreglo[$i] = $numero;
    echo $numero." ";
  }
}

echo count( $numerosJ1 );
```

... me asalta la duda sobre qué forma sería más idónea para hacer lo que quieres. Sería quizá motivo para una pregunta interesante.

Comment: ¡ Huy ! Cierto en lo de mi error. Pero tu respuesta no es acorde a la pregunta. Pregunta por como modificar desde dentro de una función un `array` pasado como argumento, no como crear una función que devuelva un `array` :-)

Comment: @Trauma el planteamiento es este: *... un array... en el cual pienso guardar valores enteros aleatorios haciendo uso de una función ...*, por la expresión *haciendo uso de una función* puede entenderse de las dos maneras, no dice específicamente que quiere pasar el array como argumento.

Comment: Te lo concedo. Tengo tendencia a fiarme mas del código que de las palabras :-) +1

Comment: @Trauma, mi respuesta iba encaminada a mostrar que se puede hacer de las dos maneras. Mi duda ahora es ¿cuál de las dos formas es la mejor para este caso? El sentido común me dice que para este caso no amerita pasar el array a la función, porque se trata de generar algo nuevo a partir de cero... otra cosa sería si se quisiera trabajar a partir de un array con datos para modificar parte de él o algo así.

Comment: Ummm ... buena pregunta. Sin ser experto en PHP, diría que el paso por referencia es mas *ligero* que el copiar un *array* (tanto como argumento como en el return). Pero en alguna parte leí que el interprete optimiza el paso/retorno de valores usando técnicas de *CopyOnWrite* y referencias implícitas ... en un código tan simple, supongo que habrá poca diferencia. En el caso de encadenar llamadas reutilizando *array*s ... habría que hacer benchmark ...

Comment: @Trauma [las opiniones están divididas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/178328/5587982) en el homólogo inglés de este sitio. [La respuesta con más votos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3845530/5587982) indica que pasar por valor es más rápido que pasar por referencia, lo mismo parece indicar la respuesta aceptada. Luego hay comentarios que contradicen tanto una postura como la otra, o indican que depende de si es un array grande o no, o de la cantidad de iteracciones.

Answer (score 3):

Podrias simplificar el programa generando unicamente lo que necesitas dentro de la funcion en un solo bloque de codigo. Pasar un arreglo por referencia en este caso no es necesario. Es mejor verificar si la funcion necesita ser parametrizada y en que manera afecta la legibilidad general.

```
function numerosJugadores() { 
    // no se declaran variables internamente
    return array_map(function() {  return rand(1,45); }, range(0,6));
}

$jugadores = numerosJugadores(); // una sola llamada
```