# Pasar por valor, por referencia o no pasar nada en PHP: ¿qué es más eficaz?

Tags: php, buenas-prácticas

Ayer [estuve discutiendo con @Trauma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/198787/problemas-simples-con-arrays-php/198799?noredirect=1#comment372793_198799) sobre la eficacia entre pasar un array a una función por valor, por referencia o no pasar nada.

Consideremos cada caso en una función:

#### Por referencia

```
$arr=array();

funtion byReference(&$arr){
   //trabajar con el array
}
```

---

#### Por valor

```
$arr=array();

funtion byValue($arr){
   //trabajar con el array
}
```

---

#### Nada (crear el array dentro de la función y retornalo)

```
$arr=byNothing();

funtion byNothing(){
    $arr=array();
   //trabajar con el array
    return $arr;
}
```

La pregunta es: **¿cuál es más eficaz de estos tres métodos?**

He leído sobre todo las respuestas a la pregunta: ***[In PHP (>= 5.0), is passing by reference faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/178328/5587982)*** pero las respuestas en sí son contradictorias. Unas dicen que es más rápido por valor, otras que por referencia  y no hablan del tercer caso porque no era abordado en la pregunta.

No teniendo posibilidad de probarlo, planteo aquí la pregunta esperando tener un concepto claro sobre el rendimiento, basado en resultados hechos sobre pruebas reales si fuera posible.

Comment: ¿El enlace de "In PHP (>= 5.0) ..." es el correcto? Porque lleva a una pregunta sobre Java y no pone mucho sobre PHP

Comment: @JaviMollá cierto, enlacé otra pregunta sin querer. Gracias por señalarlo, ya está corregido.

Comment: Supongo que en el segundo caso, al pasarlo por valor, tendrías que inicializar un nuevo array y devolverlo, si lo que intentas hacer con dicha función es realizar algún tipo de modificación sobre los elementos del array

Comment: @JaviMollá en mi lógica el 2º caso aplicaría cuando se requiere modificar el mismo array, pero en la discusión con Trauma él parece haber leído que es mucho mejor por referencia en ese caso. Y... parece que la opción 3 también es más costosa. Yo entendía justo lo contrario (en mi lógica), por eso he planteado la pregunta.

Comment: No puedo aportar pruebas ni resultados pero, en general, nunca uso el paso por referencia. Me quedo con los dos últimos casos y ya depende de si necesito el valor del array actual para pasarlo a la función. Por lo que he leído en el post que has enlazado, no queda nada claro lo de la ganancia en rendimiento además de que depende mucho de la implementación de PHP, que podría cambiar de una versión a otra. A no ser que fuera algo que recomendaran encarecidamente en toda la documentación de PHP, yo seguiría usando el paso por valor

Comment: Yo pienso que el método debería tener la capacidad de ejecutarse le envíen o no valores y retornar algo por defecto para mantener la fluidez del sistema que se este creando, por ejemplo `function test($x=null){ return ($x==null) ? ["Sin Datos"] : $x; }`, en cuanto al rendimiento va a depender de muchos factores, es un tema largo que tendrá muchas opiniones

Comment: EL problema que veo aca (no con la pregunta, es buenisima) es que no encuentro por ningun lado el manual de referencia del lenguaje de PHP. No el manual de funciones, si no el manual que refiere como debe compilarse cada instruccion. Porque de eso depende totalmente la respuesta. Si encontramos eso, podemos hacer una comparacion aunque sea teoria. Igual, eso no implica que cada compilador de php pueda hacer lo que quiera con lo que se le pasa.

Comment: @gbianchi ¿no existe documentación de PHP parecida a [JVM internals](http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html), por ejemplo?

Comment: @A.Cedano no la he encontrado por ningun lado.. debe existir, pero no se donde...

Comment: Ahora tengo un par de dudas: Cuándo podemos decir que es eficaz? cuando demora menos en ejecutarse, cuando consume menos memoria?, otros factores...  como dice la canción "todo depende". Para el caso propuesto hice una prueba de escritura en la cual las 3 funciones agregan 1.000.000 de veces el mismo valor al array, (con valores random el comportamiento fue bastante similar, quise evitarlo para descartar latencia de memoria/tiempo de dicha función ya que en esos aspectos le hace bastante honor al nombre), ..(continúa... )

Comment: resultados de memoria: por referencia me consume 0,02 bytes más que el resto (la nada misma), en cuanto a tiempo: lo ejecuté n veces y nunca un método resalto significativamente respecto a otro, la ejecución fue por separado y en conjunto alternando el orden. Seguramente hay otros factores de server, version de PHP, servidor web, etc.que pueden influir, yo lo ejecute en local con PHP7 (vuela con el SSD) dejo un link en donde hay info. referente a como PHP almacena las variables en su contenedor "zval" y hace sus trucos de optimización http://php.net/manual/es/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php

Comment: @A.Cedano, si de [eficacia](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=eficacia) se trata, todas tienen la "_capacidad de lograr el efecto que se desea_". Me parece que lo buscas saber es la [eficiencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia) o "Efectividad"

Answer (score 1):

Si de [eficiencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eficiencia) se trata, entonces supongamos el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<?php

function byRef(&$arr){
    $arr[] = '';
}
function byVal($arr){
    $arr[] = '';
    return $arr;
}
function byRet(){
    $arr = [];
    $arr[] = '';
    return $arr;
}

//
$times = 4; // Cantidad de veces para promediar
$max = 1000000; // Cantidad de veces a ejecutar la funcion

//
$avg = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < $times; $x++) {
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $ref = [];
        byRef($ref);
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $avg[] = $time_end - $time_start;
}
echo "byRef: ~". number_format(array_sum($avg) / $times, 10) . " segs<br>\n";

//
$avg = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < $times; $x++) {
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $in = [];
        $out = byVal($in);
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $avg[] = $time_end - $time_start;
}
echo "byVal: ~". number_format(array_sum($avg) / $times, 10) . " segs<br>\n";

//
$avg = [];
for ($x = 0; $x < $times; $x++) {
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
        $ret = byRet();
    }
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $avg[] = $time_end - $time_start;
}
echo "byRef: ~". number_format(array_sum($avg) / $times, 10) . " segs<br>\n";
```

Resultados en `PHP 7.0.8`:

```
byRef: ~0.1306226850 segs
byVal: ~0.1826439500 segs
byRet: ~0.1372624636 segs
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/SQDC60434)</kbd>

Dichos resultados, varían de ejecución en ejecución.
En mis pruebas por lo general **`byVal` es el mas lento**, seguido por `byRet` y **`byRef` el mas rápido**

Comment: Desde mi punto de vista es lógico que `byRef` sea mas eficiente que los demas, ya que pasar por referencia implica pasar el `puntero a memoria` en lugar de tener que crear y reservar memoria para una nueva variable.